# "Error: Maximum attempt count reached" when querying for unread message count

Tags: javascript, notifications, twilio

I have a JS file that contains the codes for managing notifications on our platform. It queries for the unread message count, using the getUnconsumedMessagesCount function on the channel object.

When it runs, most of the time it will return the count properly.  However, sometimes I get an error "Maximium attempt count reached" and will continue to get this error and not the message count.  Any reason why I am encountering this error?

Code Snippet

```
var tempChannel = channelObj.channel;
var promise = tempChannel.getUnconsumedMessagesCount();
promise.then(function (count) { console.log(count); }.catch(function(){});
```

Comment: Sounds like you are over your limit of calls....

Comment: It would appear that the error has nothing to do with the code you have posted, but is rather being returned from the call to `channelObj.getUnconsumedMessagesCount()`. As @epascarello noted, you probably have an upper limit on the number of calls you can make (per day/hour/minute?).

Comment: @epascarello where can I see my accounts limits?  This is chat feature does need to update and sync between the tabs to show the current counter (business requirement)

Comment: Don't they have a support line?

Comment: How are you using this code? How often is it called? There are [limits on Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/chat-limits) but not specifically on reading the unread count. Let me know and I'll try to find out more.

Comment: We are using the code to query for unread messages.  Currently we do a query every 15 seconds to sync up different tabs to display the same count for each tab if available.  For this instance it is a single tab user with ~20 channels checking for notifications every 15 seconds.  I can work out better logic to handle this, but this was not found in testing since we did not reach the cap.  Thank you for the link.